# Redirect domain name to IP

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, wamp

Using a Wamp configuration, and I have a .htaccess file in both the root and subfolder (www and www/myPage)

```
Options All -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#
# Redirect all requests for all non-canonical domains to same page in www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```

In my webhotels DNS config i redirect to the specific IP but it doesn´t work, yet it seemed to work when I had the domain under a different computer. I want all requests to both the servers direct IP and the domain to end up in www/myPage but with the URL:
www.example.com .

Does this .htaccess end me up in a loop or what´s the problem? Scoured several similiar threads and tested a few options this one seemed the "best" to me but still not working. Rewrite module is enabled.

UPDATE:

Ok so now I removed the htaccess file from the root folder, and I can reach the server now via the domain name. Problem is I get to the root with both the domain name and IP address so I have to click the appropriate folder and then get the url www.example.com/myPage as the address for the index file. Should I use a htaccess file in the root folder ? I added an alias through the apache commandline but didnt seem to help.

Comment: you're redirecting www.example.com to www.example.com. What is the purpose of this redirection?

Comment: @V-X www.example.com is excluded (`!`) from the redirect.

Comment: all right. sorry; 
So, what is the problem? Do you have access logs? There you'll clearly see, if you get redirected or if the request missed the webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also setup appropriate [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias)s in your main config or virtual host section.

Comment: Wamps apache had a way to easily add an Alias, so I added localhost/myPage/ to point to c:/wamp/www/myPage/ . I Get 403 error now though "You don't have permission to access / on this server". I got this error before adding the serveralias as well though so not blaming that, but it´s weird... I could reach correct page no problem before I did the redirects in the htaccess files and DNS change to the webhotel. There MIGHT be some delay on the webhotels part though so I´ll check back in about 20 minutes and see if it has worked.

Comment: @user1948698 `ServerAlias` and `Alias` are two different things!

Comment: <Directory C:/wamp/www>
AllowOverride All
Order Deny,Allow   
Allow from all 
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>   
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\myPage" #It doesn't matter if you use forward or backslashes
ServerName www.myPage.com #This should be the same domain that you entered in your "hosts" file
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Followed a shorter guide to get to the point of adding those things and also including the vhosts conf through the apache conf file. But if I use those options wamp won´t even start, this is driving me crazy... I reach my page now through IP and domain but I reach the root so I have to click the folder to get to the correct page. so it´s www.myPage.com/myPage

Comment: I ended up just changing the root path in my httpd.conf to the subfolder after the initial redirect got working from the webhotel, so now it works as it´s supposed to. If I want to run more than one website from the same setup I probably have to do something about it though.